# Update/Install Network Adapter driver on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, steam, adapter

Iconsider myself linux newbie even after using it for a year for web development. I'm gaming and encountering Network problems when playing Steam games like CS:GO & DOTA 2.

I know this is a Steam app issue but some forum 7 years ago seems to have solve their problem for Steam games/Steam app itself disabling their network adapter by updating/changing their network adapter driver , obviously that forum is talking about windows.

Basically, Steam games kills their LAN connection to the modem, it would say "CABLE UNPLUGGED" on the network(ubuntu) and it only happens on Steam games.

Now this is Ubuntu so I have no idea how to tinker around linux.

I don't know what I'm posting but I hope this helps you in helping me how to update/change my network adapter driver.

```
nico@nico-desktop:~$ sudo lshw -C network

*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 10
       serial: bc:5f:f4:0a:8d:d3
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=sb ip=192.168.1.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:38 memory:d0310000-d031ffff memory:d0300000-d030ffff memory:fe500000-fe5007ff
```

```
nico@nico-desktop:~$ ifconfig -a

enp6s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::ba83:fde8:4446:36d0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether bc:5f:f4:0a:8d:d3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10389  bytes 10618957 (10.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8868  bytes 1500554 (1.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 38  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 817  bytes 477744 (477.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 817  bytes 477744 (477.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
nico@nico-desktop:~$ ip -s a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    483617     888      0       0       0       0       
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    483617     888      0       0       0       0       
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:0a:8d:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.7/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp6s0
       valid_lft 85134sec preferred_lft 85134sec
    inet6 fe80::ba83:fde8:4446:36d0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    23956681   19731    0       0       0       19      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    2102688    15210    0       0       0       0
```

```
nico@nico-desktop:~$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD9x0/RX980 Host Bridge (rev 02)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GFX port 0)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 0)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 1)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 2)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 4)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890/RD9x0/RX980 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI Express GPP Port 5)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X] (rev c7)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580]
02:00.0 IDE interface: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE912x SATA 6Gb/s Controller [IDE mode] (rev 12)
03:00.0 USB controller: Etron Technology, Inc. EJ168 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
04:00.0 USB controller: Etron Technology, Inc. EJ168 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
05:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6315 Series Firewire Controller
05:00.1 IDE interface: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6415 PATA IDE Host Controller (rev a0)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
```